# jQuery animate and scrollTop not working unless app is mobile size

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

I have the following code which does not work in the desktop size but does work when I resize my app.

```
 $('#accordion').on('shown.bs.collapse', function (e) {
            e.preventDefault();
            var id = $(e.target).prev().find("[id]")[0].id;
            console.log(id);
            //navigateToElement(id);

            $('body').animate({
                scrollTop: $("#" + id).offset().top
            }, 1000);
        });
```

Here is what's happing, the only difference in the app is that I'm hiding the left navigation and top dropdown in the header

[image]

Comment: I've never came across this issue. Can you set a small fiddle for us?

Comment: Or maybe debug step-by-step in developer tools to see where the code might break. Also, hard refresh or disable caching.

Comment: @hardcoresquirrel when I did a fiddle it's fine, it has something to do with my CSS

Comment: Do you have custom CSS(some media query) that aims `#accordion` ? Post that here then.

Comment: noting on the accordion, I'm thinking it has something to do with body, html or the media tag. My App css is here - http://jsfiddle.net/Ln6twqzw/ Its two files. I can't figure out what's casing the conflict

Comment: Well, that's 5k of CSS lines :) Do a step-by-step debug in Developer Tools. Add a breakpoint at each line, and take a look if everything isn't broken. There might be a new bug.

Comment: I see you're setting `overflow-x` to `hidden` on the html, body in your media query `@media (max-width: 767px)` ..

Comment: @BrettCaswell your right it's the overflow-x hidden

Comment: @BrettCaswell any ideas why the overflow x is affecting it, I need to have it hidden

Comment: @almog, I'm not sure what you mean: `overflow-x` is hidden in the 'mobile' view (or when `width` is less then `767px`)..

Comment: as far as to why `overflow` is affecting jQuery's `scrollTo` function (when set to 'auto' or 'visible'.. the heart of the reasoning lies in the spec: http://www.w3.org/TR/2007/WD-css3-box-20070809/#other

Comment: by the way, I can't tell if your running this code in a device emulator (google supports emulating devices).. you'll certainly want to consider touch events..

Answer (score 3):

The issue is with overflow-x: hidden in the CSS

```
@media (min-width: 768px) {
  html,
  body {
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    overflow-x: hidden;
  }
```

Comment: "the issue was with `overflow-x: hidden;` not being present on `@media (min-width: 768px)`". For, it was present on `@media (max-width:767px)`. the answer was to add the `overflow` declaration; However, your recent comment above indicates that this doesn't actually hide the `desktop` view properly?

Answer (score 0):

Could you provide the markup? While you do that, could you try moving the

```
e.preventDefault();
```

To the bottom of the function to see if that solves the problem.

Comment: e.preventDefault(); doesn't solve the issue and it should be there that was a mistake

Answer (score 0):

Check your target element, I am guessing the target element is somehow floating to the right, and when you clicking on it, The event didn't get picked up.